# How does Open Office Calc make this conversion?

Tags: openoffice, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

In a column, I have dates of the format 2013-05-27. When I selected "Default Formatting", the dates got changed to five digits, for example, 41422. Where does this number come from? It's not even subtracting the numbers.

Answer (score 4):

It's the number of days passed from Friday, December 29, 1899 and your date.

References & proofs:

- [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=41422%20days%20before%202013-05-27) - calculation proof
- *[System time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_time)* (Wikipedia) - note that on other systems / software this date is different.
- [Data types in VB](http://www.promotic.eu/en/pmdoc/ScriptLangs/VBScript/DataTypes.htm) - scroll down to "Notes for **Date** data type".
- [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/205719) - "Office spreadsheet" proof. Note that Excel's reference date is a day later after 29.12.1899: `January 0, 1900` which equals to 30.12.1899.
- [Firebird Support](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/firebird-support/message/39454) - indirect proof, but when a value isn't entered the date turns to 30.12.1899
- *[Epoch (reference date), Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29#Computing)* (Wikipedia) - another table of additional reference dates

Comment: Do elaborate from where this arbitrary starting date of December 29, 1899 comes from?

Comment: I don't know, it's just a common regulation. I don't think it has special meaning or something; I suppose the first developers to implement this just thought "it would be nice to begin from 1900" or something like this.

Comment: Thanks I've never heard of this. Could you share a source of this information? Do other spreadsheets or other programs use this magic date?

Comment: Excel 2013 does this too, though it outputs `41421` (might be timezone stuff)

Comment: 2 examples [here](http://www.promotic.eu/en/pmdoc/ScriptLangs/VBScript/DataTypes.htm) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/205719). Also, according ton [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_time) different systems calculate time relatively to different dates. 
By the way, my answer was an educated guess. I remembered something about "date-relative to.." so I checked it up on [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=41422+days+before+2013-05-27).

Comment: @SzymonSzydełko MS Excel does it relatively to the day after: January 1, 1900. [proof](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/205719)

Comment: Well, Excel and OpenOffice being out-of-step in terms of day-numbers has to do with a deviation concerning whether or not 1900 is treated as a leap year.  (Excel maintaining compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3 meant that it also had the leap-year bug.)

Comment: I think @orcmid is correct. See http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html